# Symfony 2 - Keep a variable between actions without Session

Tags: php, symfony, global-variables, twig, event-listener

I have a Controller's action (we can call it `listPageAction`). This action manage my main view (a list of elements). These elements can be filtered (it's managed on this same Action).

I want to keep the filters values between my differents pages (=Actions), and recover them when I go back into ma main view (`listPageAction`).

I cannot use the `session`, because the app is frequently used in multiple tabs of the browser, so the session can collid.

I cannot pass "manually" the filters elements, because from the others pages, I can arrive on others pages and so on (It's a hierarchical list of pages). It's not optimal to pass 3 variables to each route, to each action.

Use global variable will be good, but I'm not sure if it's possible like a classical global variable in PHP. I have read few things with the global variable from Twig (which I use for the renders). It will be possible for my need ? How ?

Other possibility I have identify (but I don't know how I can use it), will be to use `Listener`. I think I can add my filters value in each response (`kernel.response`). 
But, I don't know how I can pass to my listener the filters, and how I can recover them on `listPageAction` when I come back on the main page.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can give manually a unique parameter between each page, a **key**.

This way you can use the session, use the key to difference them between multiple tabs.

url would be `page/{key}/step1` and `page/{key}/step2`
the session storing the objects would be like `$session->get($key.".object");`

Comment: I think it isn't the best solution, but currently I don't have a better idea. I don't like very much the fact to edit all my routes to add the `key` into the URL. But with my constraints... I take that for the moment ! Thanks.